# .Select exclude item if item.x = null

Tags: c#, linq

I need to create a new object and add it to a list but if one of the fields is null I don't want to include it in my list.

Is there a way to not select the `item` if `item.Group.Label` is equal to `null`

```
var search = Db.*******.Find(accountId);
var suggestions = Db.*******.Where(
                           x => x.Name.Contains(search.Name) 
                             && x.EntityId != accountId)
                           .ToList()
                           .Select(item => new { 
                                                  id = item.GroupId, 
                                                  text = item.Group.Label
                                               });

return Json(suggestions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: You can add to your .Where --> (x.Group!=null && x.Group.Label!=null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include that condition in your `Where` function?

```
var suggestions = Db.*******
     .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search.Name) && 
         x.EntityId != accountId && x.Group.Label != null)
     .ToList()
     .Select(item => new { id = item.GroupId, text = item.Group.Label});
```

Comment: Thanks just added `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Group.Label)`